# How sould I document dimensions of a pointed-to buffer?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

This is a "doxygen style/etiquette" question.

I have a function which takes, say, an `int *buffer`. Now, `buffer` is actually a multi-dimensional array, with different dimensions in each axis, and the coordinates each having some significance.

In a more typical doxygen comment, I might write:

```
@param[in] foo The quick brown fox
@param[in] bar A lazy dog.
```

and this is one-sentence, or at most one-paragraph, oriented.

Is there a common practice of how to document the dimensions and axes of `buffer`? And should I place them after `buffer`'s `@param` entry, or elsewhere, and refer to it from `buffer`'s `@param`?

Comment: I am not a Doxygen expert, but I  doubt there is a "canonical convention" for this, as there is none when you would just use free comments for documenting input parameters. However, I would write a simple synopsis, like:  `// access by buffer[ROWSIZE * col + row]`, that should by crystal clear to most readers

Comment: @DocBrown: This is not sufficient, because:  1. It doesn't say how many rows there are 2. It doesn't explain what the row and column mean. 3. There might not be a fixed compile-time constant called `ROWSIZE`; it may be a value that's implicit and requires some computation to get at.

Comment: This was an example for you to get the idea. I am sure you won't need more than one or two additional lines to describe the missing pieces.

Comment: How does the function know what `buffer` actually is?

Comment: @mouviciel: The function doesn't know what its parameters "actually" are. It may make certain assumptions about them (e.g. how many elements are accessible via a pointer), but that's it. But I know what the function is intended to receive.

Comment: @einpoklum huh?? it doesn't know what they are??

Comment: @user253751: Knowledge is something very deep. A function just needs to do something, it doesn't need to "know" things.

Comment: @einpoklum heading way too far into the philosophy weeds. When the computer runs the function the function somehow tells the computer what to do. Obviously the function is able to provide that information to the computer.

Comment: and somehow *the programmer* knows what is in the buffer, too!

Comment: You could just say something like "multidimensional fixed-size array; dimensions: [foo (20), bar (10), baz (5)]", where foo, bar & baz are the semantic names for each dimension (axis). Or some other format, like "dimensions (foo, bar, baz) with lengths (20, 10, 5)", or less wordy, but potentially less clear "(foo, bar, baz) = (20, 10, 5)"

Comment: Function documentation shall focus on which assumptions it makes about `buffer`.

Comment: @mouviciel: Assumptions can also go beyond what's written in the code. They can involve the rationale for doing what the function does.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović: It doesn't sound like you're describing a common convention...

Comment: There's no commonly accepted convention across all of software development (in part because such unstructured data is generally avoided); use something that will make sense to your intended developer audience (e.g. "20x10x5") in combination with a short description. Alternatively, provide a helper function/object that will let devs build the parameter without having to know the details of the parameter's structure in memory. The convention is actually not that important, what we care as developers is for you to be clear how can we meet the data format and the preconditions for this function.

Comment: You can define a user-defined type that precisely describes the multi-dimensional extent of your array. If the size is fixed (i.e. a compile-time constant), you can still define it as a size struct with constant integers or even a constant array. Many libraries do that; e.g. libtorch.

Comment: In case you're programming with C++, refer to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/array for examples of declaring a reference (or pointer) to a multidimensional array of compile-time sizes. Example syntax: `void Func(const int (&arr)[64][8][8]) {...}` Pay attention to the parentheses surrounding the variable name, with lvalue (or even rvalue) qualifiers, etc.

Comment: You are correct. In this case, I would put this rationale in the function's description, not in the parameter's.

Comment: @rwong: I didn't say it was C++. Also, I didn't say it was in an environment where the standard library is available; nor, actually, that the sizes are known at compile time.

Comment: @einpoklum That's fine, but I think you can extrapolate/adjust from the suggestions so far. We've produced several ideas, approaching the problem in a number of alternate ways (descriptions in documentation, semantics via helper functions, semantics via a data type) - I'm sure you can take the ideas and adjust them to suit your project/environment, or use them as inspiration to come up with your own idea (that could, given your familiarity with the project, end up being better than anything we can suggest).